# How to change audio volume by scrolling in the whole area of the top bar

Tags: 22.04

How to change the audio volume by scrolling in the whole area of the top bar?
Now it's possible only by scrolling on the audio icon in that top bar.

I'm using Ubuntu 15.10 64bit.

Thanks